# Bind datatemplate image to an attribute of custom object in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a collection
`private ObservableCollection<ImageData> imageDataList = new ObservableCollection<ImageData>();` where ImageData is a custom object. It has an attribute called `fileName` a string that stores full path of an image file. In my XAML code, I have a listbox with datatemplate as the following.

```
<ListBox Name="listBox_ImageList" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" SelectionChanged="listBox_ImageList_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding fileName}" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

After populating `ImagaData` objects into `imageDataList`, I set `this.listBox_ImageList.ItemsSource = imageDataList;`

However, when I run it, I don't see any images. Can you please tell me how to databind properly to a string member of an object to WPF image source?

Comment: do you see _anything_?  what do you see if you comment out ListBox.ItemTemplate code (you should see [ImagaData.ToString()])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/f94cc770-8d86-4a9f-a5f9-2ee2ea146c1a

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataContext to where the object where the ObservableCollection is located

```
DateContext = this;
```

Also instead of fileName bind it to a ImageSource Property or a BitmapImage Property and this is created using the fileName.

Comment: I suppose you can use a converter like Juan Carlos Vega Neira suggested

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: You cannot bind the ImageSource property to a string. It works in XAML because WPF uses a default converter from string to ImageSource when you set the value in XAML. If you want to set the value with a binding or from code you need to provide an ImageSource object.

There are 2 ways to do it via binding:

The first one is presented [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/f94cc770-8d86-4a9f-a5f9-2ee2ea146c1a) (the link Juan Carlos mentioned), and it involves creating a IValueConverter that will take your string and transform it to a ImageSource. I would modify the converter code presented there with this:

```
public sealed class StringToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        }
        catch 
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The second option is to create your ImageSource in your ImageData class and bind directly to it.

```
private ImageSource _imageSource
public ImageSource ImageSource
{
  get
  {
    if (_imageSource == null)
    {
      _imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }
    return _imageSource;
  }
}
```